# Endless loop recur

Tags: loops, clojure, tail-recursion

I'm learning Clojure and I've just started on [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) and I've run into a problem I cannot figure out. Here is my code:

```
(defn largest_prime_factor
  [x]
  (if (prime? x) x)
  (loop [running x divider 2]
    (if (= 0 (mod running divider))
      (let [d (/ running divider)]
        (if (prime? d)
          d
          (recur d 2)))
      (recur x (inc divider)))))

(largest_prime_factor 12)  ;works
(largest_prime_factor 49)  ;works
(largest_prime_factor 147) ;Endless loop!
```

I realise that this might not be the most efficient way to find the largest prime factor but what I'm trying to figure out is why it gets stuck in a loop. Obviously I'm using loop-recur the wrong way but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things

```
(defn largest_prime_factor
  [x]
  (if (prime? x) x)                 ; #1
  (loop [running x divider 2]
    (if (= 0 (mod running divider))
      (let [d (/ running divider)]
        (if (prime? d)
          d
          (recur d 2)))
      (recur x (inc divider)))))    ; #2
```

1. The extra closing parenthesis makes this a self-contained `if` without an `else` clause. This has no bearing on the infinite loop, but would give the wrong answer (1) for a prime input (unless you start your divider at 1 instead, in which case you can omit this initial test).
2. This line should recur with `running` rather than `x`, otherwise you have not factored out the divisor and the `prime?` test will ever after be false. This is why you wind up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you. I was focusing too much on the other recur

Answer (score 3):

```
(if (prime? x) x)
```

I think you mean

```
(if (prime? x) x
  (loop [...
```